# Mongoose Aggregate & Sum conditonally

Tags: mongoose

I've struggled with this question for the whole day, and so I come to you with it now.

I have a set of products defined liked that :

```js
// Product schema
{
 brand: String,
 size: String,
 colour: String,
 ...
}
```

I am looking for all items from one brand and with the following filter :

```js
// Standard filtered search
const match = {
 brand: 'brand1'
}
Product.find(match)
```

It returns me two results :

```js
// Result set
{ brand: 'brand1', size: 'M', colour: 'RED', ... },
{ brand: 'brand1', size: 'S', colour: 'GREEN', ... }
```

**Now to the problem i face :**
I would like to get out, for each filter (brand, size, colour, ...), a list of grouped possible values (red, green, M, S, brand1, brand2, ...), and their corresponding sum in the actual filtered result set.
I don't know how to explain it correctly, but here is the result I would like :

```js
[{
    "brand": [
        {
            "_id": "brand1",
            "count": 2
        }, {
            "_id": "brand2",
            "count": 0
        }, {
            "_id": "brand3",
            "count": 0
        }
    ],
    "size": [
        {
            "_id": "M",
            "count": 1
        }, {
            "_id": "S",
            "count": 1
        }, {
            "_id": "L",
            "count": 0
        }
    ],
    "colour": [
        {
            "_id": "RED",
            "count": 1
        }, {
            "_id": "GREEN",
            "count": 1
        }, {
            "_id": "ORANGE",
            "count": 0
        }
    ],
}]
```

**What I tried**
I manage to get this structure with the following aggregate query ; It groups all the keys, but sums them all up, representing the global database, and not the filtered one. If I add a { $match: ... } before the $facet, it groups only the available keys of the filter, and omits the ones that should be zeroed ...

```js
// Doesn't work : All the keys with sum 0 are ignored
Product.aggregate([
    { 
        $facet: {
          brand: [{ $sortByCount: "$brand" }],
          size: [{ $sortByCount: "$size" }],
          colour: [{ $sortByCount: "$colour" }],
          ...
        }
    }    
])
```

```js
// Doesn't work : All keys are present, but the sums are not right
Product.aggregate([
    {
        $match:  { brand: "brand1" }
    },
    { 
        $facet: {
          brand: [{ $sortByCount: "$brand" }],
          size: [{ $sortByCount: "$size" }],
          colour: [{ $sortByCount: "$colour" }],
          ...
        }
    }    
])
```

I hope It was clear, I did the best I could to explain my problem, and I would be gratful if someone could bring an idea to the table :)

If you need more information, please just ask.

Comment: it is working properly see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fwopFnetpll)

Comment: Something that wasn't clear maybe : I do this search : [find playgroud](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-opYTFtdzs3) and then i would like to return the aggregated filter. What happens is i can either return the filter with the count and groups of the find or of the original. But i cannot group all items from original, and count only the one from the find ... It is complicated to explain ... I'll try to find a way to explain better ...

Comment: how can we understand that your *Something wasn't clear maybe*?

Comment: Srry I clicked enter by mistake, hadn't finished my message ...

Comment: I would like, taking your playground as example, to have brand2 with a cout of 0 (As it is not included in the search output, where i search for only brand1 items)

Comment: put the match stage like [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OqaBIzGOzAn)

Comment: But like that I do not see "brand2" with a count of 0 ...

Comment: ah i got your question, its really long process, will try if possible.

Comment: Srry, it"s quite difficult to explain at first haha ^^ Thanks by the way ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$set` to create a field like `searchBrand`, check your condition if brand is your search branch then set it to 1 otherwise 0
- `$group` by specific field in facet and count that `searchBrand` field
- `$sort` by `count` in descending order

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      searchBrand: {
        $cond: [{ $eq: ["$brand", "brand1"] }, 1, 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      brand: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$brand",
            count: { $sum: "$searchBrand" }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { count: -1 } }
      ],
      size: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$size",
            count: { $sum: "$searchBrand" }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { count: -1 } }
      ],
      colour: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$colour",
            count: { $sum: "$searchBrand" }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { count: -1 } }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T4K2gv1BHu-)

Comment: Oh, it seems to be it. I look at it this afternoon, and accept if all ok. Thx a lot !

Comment: Perfect I tested it out, it work just fine ! Thanks a lot. I will now adapt the search conditions to match my globl search. But It's great to be able to have all that in one and only query :)